# How to pass on splat arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Given a class that has method which accepts a splat, for example a method you get from `ActiveRecord::FinderMethods`:

```
class Settle
  def self.find(*args)
  end
end
```

How should I call that method from another method, say another class, so that it has the exact same signature?

```
class Settler
  def self.find(*args)
    Settle.find(*args)
  end
end
```

Or

```
class Settler
  def self.find(*args)
    Settle.find(args)
  end
end
```

Or something else?
Note that **the exact same signature** is the important part: `Settler.find` should work exactly similar to `Settle.find`.

I am not, however, interested in code that allows the `Settler.find` signature to magically update whenever `Settle.find` changes into something completely different, like e.g. `.find(scope, *args)`. In that case, updating the version in `Settler` is no problem.

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to pass arguments received with splat as separate arguments, or do you want to pass a method's signature to another?

Comment: Your editing of the question made it unclear @sawa. I'm reverting it manually to answer your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be

```ruby
Settle.find(*args)
```

This way, all the arguments passed into `Settler.find`, are passed also to `Settle.find` and stored in `args` array inside of it. So the `args` arrays inside of both methods hold the same value.

Passing arguments as 'splat' is quite simple - it's just passing an array as separate arguments. So if you have

```ruby
ar = [arg1, arg2, arg3, argn]
```

calling

```ruby
some_method(*ar)
```

is equivalent to

```ruby
some_method(arg1, arg2, arg3, argn)
```

Comment: Where can we find more information on passing splat arguments into methods? I am familiar with accepting splat arguments, but not so much with passing them into other methods.

Comment: Passing arguments as 'splat' is quite simple - it's just passing array as separate arguments. So if you have `ar = [arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn]`, calling `some_method(*ar)` is equivalent to `some_method(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argn)`, that's all.

Comment: perfect! That was the summary I was looking for. Could you include this in the answer? Then it's precicely the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: The safest one is `*[*args]`, that will work properly even if args is a variable.